# Integrating Angular 4 view with ASP.NET MVC 5 in visual studio 17

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-5, package.json

I am learning Angular and MVC.I am trying to integrate Angular into my Asp.Net MVC-5 project in Visual Studio 17 so that I can create Angular views for my project.I downloaded the quickstart files and copied the required files into the project and when I tried to restore the packages from the package.json, but I am getting the following error

"npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue"

What do these errors mean and how do I fix this.

I am able to build Angular apps from the CLI separately though, but I am getting this error when I try to integrate Asp.net-MVC5 and Angular.

Comment: Those are not errors, they are warnings. You can ignore them, and move on, more than likely without any issues.

Comment: Yes, I just got it working thanks.